# List item in horizontal dropdown menu falling apart when viewed on a mac

Tags: html, css, macos, safari

I am using a css dropdown horizontal menu from a template I modified. I have a mac but use a virtual machine from which I designed the website in question. It works on all browsers in the Windows based virtual machine however after I launched it when viewed on the mac it is dropping my last list item down underneath the first list item in all browsers viewed on the mac.

The dropdown menu has three external style sheets attached to it plus my style sheet for the associated page. Here is the temporary IP address:

http://174.120.170.93/~emoree/test.html

I feel like it is a simple solution but I am not the best programmer so I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

The width on ul.dropdown is set to 425px in dropdown.css (line 27). This is not wide enough for all three list items, which are floated so the third one drops below when it runs out of space.

I would remove the `width:425px` from ul.dropdown. This will cause the list items to poke out the right side of the website, so I would change div#test to `float: right;`, instead of `float: left; margin-left: 375px;`